# How to Display another html page content in my html page by using Angularjs but not others

Tags: ajax, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new to web programming. And now I am working on an application by using ionic in which it mainly focus on using angularjs. I just want to ask the stupid questions.

The situation on my application is that there are lists of img links linking to different url (.html) in which there are only contains words in the page( these pages are another websites I cannot change anything ). I just want to navigate to a new page first and displaying those contents and doing some css style from the url(.html). It is only possible to do so without using ajax but angularjs? Are there any demos for doing this?

****Edited version****
My idea is exactly the same as this tutorial(including the source code): http://css.dzone.com/articles/tutorial-how-create-responsive?page=0,2

And the live demo: http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/359/index.html#!/

But the source code here just refer to relative path url like `<a class="xxx" href="#!/project/product1" style="background-color:#87b822"/a>`.
can I refer to other websites like  `href="http://justinjackson.ca/words.html` , and add some css style to those content in my page?

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of methods of doing this

**1- ng-include**

You can use conditional ng include like, Here you can alter v

```
<div ng-include="x ? 'your-html-file.html' : null"></div>
```

for instance x is on scope

```
$scope.x = false;
$scope.setX = function(){$scope.x=true;}
```

and on img click

```
  <img ng-click="setX()">
```

**2- routing**

You can use Routing , you can download angular route and use it by injecting it into module

include it in your index page

```
<script src="js/angular-route.js"></script>
```

make pages folder and make your pages/partial templates in it

Now in app.js you can define your routes like this

```
var youApp= angular.module('youApp', ['ngRoute']);

    // configure our routes
    youApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider

            // route for the home page
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
                controller  : 'mainController'
            })

            // route for the about page
            .when('/about', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/about.html',
                controller  : 'aboutController'
            })

            // route for the contact page
            .when('/contact', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/contact.html',
                controller  : 'contactController'
            });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I got the ideas.

Comment: Excuse me, may I ask can i use external URLs for ng-include? like ng-include="www.w3schools.com". It does not show anything when I do like this <div ng-include="www.w3schools.com"></div>

Comment: No you can use your yourn partials only(although you can if other website and you set option of cross domain) "By default, the template URL is restricted to the same domain and protocol as the application document. "