# displaying HTML page in another HTML using Angular JS

Tags: html, angularjs

I am developing a Single Page Application (SPA) using Angular JS. I want to display the HTML file stored at the server in my HTML page. I am getting the address of the HTML file that I need to display in my page, but unable to display it.

I have tried `<iframe>` and ng-include but I can't display it. When I try to open the address in another tab, I am able to display it.

Comment: `ngInclude` must work, but you can also use `ngRoute`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27451294/how-to-display-another-html-page-content-in-my-html-page-by-using-angularjs-but